# C# out parameter in extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, out

In an extension method, I am receiving an error that my 'out' parameter does not exist in the current context. I assume this means that extension methods cannot have 'out' parameters, but this is not specified in the documentation. I would appreciate it if someone could please clarify!

```
public static int customMax(this int[] data, out index)
{
    int max = data[0];
    index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++) {
        if (data[i] > max) {
            max = data[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: you forgot add type (int, i think) for your `index` parameter

Comment: You also forgot to set the actual value to be returned via `index`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extension methods can have out parameters. You need to specify the type of your out parameter. So change code

```
public static int customMax(this int[] data, out index)
```

to

```
public static int customMax(this int[] data, out int index)
```

and it should all work

Comment: Thanks - I noticed this and was going to remove the question, but you were too quick!

Answer (score 0):

You've missed specifying the type on the `out` parameter.
It should read:

```
    public static int customMax(this int[] data, out int index)
```

There is some conjecture you might be interested in on another question, regarding the readability of doing this kind of thing. [Impossible to use ref and out for first ("this") parameter in Extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618597/impossible-to-use-ref-and-out-for-first-this-parameter-in-extension-methods)