# integer extension method to set an integer to 0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My code is littered with

```
someInt=0;
```

I keep constantly "resetting" my integers.

**Would it be possible to implement an extension method that will set the integer to 0?**

Something like this:

```
public static void Reset(this int num) =>num=0;
```

And the intended usage would be:

```
someInt.Reset;
```

However that will not work, since integer is a value type.

Comment: what is wrong with frequent assignment  `someInt=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a struct as a struct is a value type, i.e.

```
public struct IntegerHolder
{
    public int val;

    public reset() {
        myInt = 0
    }
}
public void main()
{
    IntegerHolder MyInteger
    MyInteger.val = 5 //Set the val to 5
    MyInteger.reset() //Reset it back to 0
}
```

But it is probably **more efficient to use int = 0** instead. just offering a usable solution

Answer (score 1):

See [Impossible to use ref and out for first ("this") parameter in Extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618597/impossible-to-use-ref-and-out-for-first-this-parameter-in-extension-methods) - you would need to use `ref` or `out` as an option for the parameter, but they're mutually-exclusive with the `this` modifier.

I don't think you have a good idea - because the code `foo = 0;` is succint and immediately obvious what it does - wrapping it in an extension method is pointless because it doesn't solve any problems, it adds complexity, and adds the potential for bugs (what if one user of `Reset` needs to reset to `1` instead of `0` and blindly changes the definition of `Reset`? It would break the rest of your code.

Don't use a language feature just because it's there - a good programmer knows when to *not* use a language feature.

If you really do want to add functionality like this, use something like T4 or make a template extension for Roslyn.