# Extension Method for degree to Radian conversion in .net

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have a variable `theetaCurrent` which is being sent by another application to me in 10th of a degree. I can very easily convert it everywhere by using a function but i want to do something like `theetaCurrent.ToRadians()`. First of all, is it possible? if yes, then how? 
Below is my current method

```
double inRadians (double angleIn10thofaDegree)
{
    // Angle in 10th of a degree
    return (angleIn10thofaDegree*Math.PI)/1800; 
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can define an [*extension method*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class Foo {

    public static double ToRadians (this double angleIn10thofaDegree) {
        // Angle in 10th of a degree
        return (angleIn10thofaDegree * Math.PI)/1800; 
    }

}
```

In boldface the changes you have to make:

- make the method `static`;
- change the name to `ToRadians`;
- add `this` to the parameter; and
- define the method in a `static` class.

You only have to change the name if you want to call it with `theetaCurrent.ToRadians()` of course.

In order to use the *extension method*, you have to **use the namespace in which `Foo` is defined**.

You can the call it with:

```
double result = original.ToRadians();
```

---

If you however aim to perform *in-place* transformations using an extension method, for example something like:

```
double theetaCurrent = 180/Math.PI;
theetaCurrent.ToRadians();
//now theetaCurrent is 0.1
```

That would be an extension method with *call-by-reference* which is - as far as I know - not supported. See [a StackOverflow answer of Jon Skeet here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618632/67579).

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have got!!! Thanks for imparting your knowledge!