# Extension method not setting value

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a product class that looks something like this -

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have an extension class that looks like this

```
public static class ProductExtension
{
    public static void FixProduct(this Product product)
    {
        product = new Product(){Name = product.Name.ToUpper()};
        //product.Name is now UPPERCASE
    }
}
```

In my Main method I have -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Product p = new Product() {ProductId = 1, Name = "steve"};
    p.FixProduct(); 
    System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

This prints `"steve"` and not what I wanted it to print: `"STEVE"`.
Why doesn't the assignment in the extension method work?

Comment: In your `FixProduct` you create a new instance of `Product`. It will be dropped by GC and does not affect your original object

Comment: `product = new Product()` redirects the variable to refer to a *new* object, not the one that was passed in as a parameter (and it should also be unnecessary, why not simply `product.Name =`)

Comment: You would need to pass `this product` as a `ref` parameter for the change in its value to be reflected outside the extension method.  However, extension methods [do not support `ref` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2618597).  You could use a [fluent style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) such as `var p = new Product {ProductId = 1, Name = "steve"}.FixProduct();`

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest a small change to follow a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern. Instead of `void`, return the new product instead. Don't use ref, that is weird.

```
public static class ProductExtension
{
    public static Product FixProduct(this Product input)
    {
        return new Product
            {
                Name = input.Name.ToUpper(),
                Id = input.Id
            }
        //product.Name is now UPPERCASE
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Product()
        {
            ProductId = 1, 
            Name = "steve"
        }
        .FixProduct();
    System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

A neat advantage of this approach is (if you think you will need it) you can support several product classes while preserving their precise type, e.g.:

```
public static class ProductExtension
{
    public static T FixProduct<T>(this T input) where T: Product, new
    {
        return new T
            {
                Name = input.Name.ToUpper(),
                Id = input.Id
            }
    }
}
```

Now you could use it on any derived product class while keeping exactly the same syntax.

```
class DeluxeProduct : Product
{ }

static void Main()
{
    var p = new DeluxeProduct
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Steve"
        }
        .FixProduct();
    Console.WriteLine(p.GetType().Name)); //outputs "DeluxeProduct"
}
```

Now on the other hand, if all you want to do is "fix" the product's name, you could just wrap it in a property.

```
class Product
{
    private string _name;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value.ToUpper(); } //Automatically "fix" it the moment you set it
    }
}
```

...and then you don't need an extension method at all.

Comment: I did this too, but it feels a little odd to have an extension method return the type of the type it is extending.

Comment: No, it is very common. In fact all of the LINQ extension methods use this pattern, as well as objects that follow a builder pattern, e.g. most IoC containers.

Comment: So in the main method: p = p.FixName(). Makes it feel like product is immutable, like when you are doing something to a string. I must be doing this all the time with LINQ and just got used to it

Comment: I figured this is just an example and there is more going on. But if you just want to force the name to uppercase, maybe wrap in a property-- I'll edit my answer to suggest this at the end.

Comment: This is a gross simplification of what I'm really doing, but it has validated that what i was originally trying can not work. Thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Extension methods cannot be used that way. In your method you create a new instance of `Product` and then assign it to `product` which is a local reference to the passed object, and not the original reference `p`.

When you first enter the function what you have is two references referencing the same object in memory.

[image]

Then just before exiting the method you have two objects, one referred by each reference, with the `product` reference, referencing a local variable being cleaned by the GC at the end of the method call.

[image]

Solutions:

1. To correct this and have it closest to what you were trying to do,
   change your method to get a `ref` parameter:

   ```
   public static void FixProduct(ref Product product)
   {
       product = new Product() { Name = product.Name.ToUpper() };
       //product.Name is now UPPERCASE
   }
   ```

   and then:

   ```
   ProductExtension.FixProduct(ref p);
   ```
2. I believe a better approach all together will be (by having it a
   member function or an extension method) to update the object instead
   of instantiating a new one:

   ```
   public static void FixProduct(this Product product)
   {
       product.Name = product.Name.ToUpper();
   }
   ```

Comment: A more elegant way would be to place it in the original `Product` class (if possible), such as `Product.Fix(prod);`

Comment: @IanH.- I agree, or still to use an extension method but jut update the object instead of creating a new one

Comment: @Bryan - you are welcome :) I'd suggest to go with the second solution I've listed

Answer (score 4):

In your extension method, you are assigning a new `Product` to the variable `product`. This doesn't end up affecting the original referenced `Product`.

Modify the method to the one below to set the name on the original passed in object.

```
public static void FixProduct(this Product product)
{
    product.Name = product.Name.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Cool, I think you were editing your post while I was writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are passed by value unless they are `ref` or `out`. `this` doesn't change that. You can understand this syntactically because `ref` and `out` require a [variable reference](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md); otherwise only an [expression](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md) is required.

Unfortunately, you can't combine `this` with `ref` or `out`.

You *can* change the value of any parameter variable, though, except in the case of `ref` or `out`, it's best avoided or limited to quick touch-ups to the passed-in value that simplify later algorithmic code.

> A method is permitted to assign new values to a value parameter. Such
>   assignments only affect the local storage location represented by the
>   value parameter—they have no effect on the actual argument given in
>   the method invocation.
>     — [C# Language Specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#value-parameters)

So, the assignment does work, just not in the `ref` or `out` way.