# Generic Extension Method for change value of any variable or object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, extension-methods

Friends, can anyone introduce a Generic Extension Method by which the value of any variable or object can be changed?

Similar to this method:

```
public static void Set<T>(this T source, T value)
{
    // some code (source = value)
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with that? It might be confusing to change a variable with an extension method

Comment: you cannot change value of source in such a way it is visible from outside you would need to have ref parameter for that and that blocks the extension method requirement

Comment: This means that there is no way to implement with Reflection and have this code?

**var n = 0;
n.Set(1);**

Comment: No, because you can only **modify** an instance by an extension-method, not **change its reference**. `0` and `1` are completey different int-instances. Why do you need that? Seems pretty odd to me. What is your actual *goal* here. Not what you think the solution might be.

Comment: what about a normal static method: `static void Set<T>(ref T source);`. Now you should be able to call it like `ExtensionClass.Set(ref myInstance);` However if you want to change a reference, why not just use `myInstance = new Whatever(...)`? In your example that'll be `var n = 0; n = 1`.

Comment: The problem was implementing a Generic method and feasibility of doing it with Reflection, and I can say I got the answer, thank you.

Comment: This was a challenge on Reflection and Generic and I was required to research it, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is impossible, as an extension-method allways works on a specific instance of a type. As every other method as well, a method can not change the instance to be something different (which would mean reference another instance), it can only **modify** that instance by calling any of its members.

If you want to know why it is forbidden to use `ref` on an extension-method, look this similar question: [Impossible to use ref and out for first ("this") parameter in Extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618597/impossible-to-use-ref-and-out-for-first-this-parameter-in-extension-methods).

On the other hand you can do that with normal methods using the `ref`-keyword, though.

```
public static void Set<T>(ref T instance)
{
    instance = new Whatever(...);
}
```

Now you may be able to use this:

```
var n = 0;
TheClass.Set(ref n);
```

However if all you want to do in that method is replacing one reference by another one, why not just use this instead?

```
var n = 0;
n = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I did not want to twist the story
But my problem was about Reflection and Generic, thank you.