# How can I change the instance that calls the static utility function from its inside?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop, static-methods

I was trying to write a utility function that will change the Vector3 's x value so I can only write

```
transform.position.SetVectorX(newX);
```

instead of:

```
Vector3 temp = new Vector3(newx, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
transform.position = temp;
```

So I tried this but I don't understand why it does not work:

```
namespace MyUtility
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static Vector3 SetVectorX(this Vector3 v, float x)
        {
            return v = new Vector3(x, v.y, v.z);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning a changed vector but are never assigning it to `transform.position`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think one level higher. You can write an extension method for the `Transform` that sets its position.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void SetPositionX(this Transform t, float x)
    {
        var v = t.Position;
        t.Position = new Vector3(x, v.y, v.z);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
transform.SetPositionX(newX);
```

As for your original idea, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618597/impossible-to-use-ref-and-out-for-first-this-parameter-in-extension-methods).